# How to open a new tab with new terminator process?

Tags: terminator

I am trying to open a new terminator tab using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>t</kbd> but it opens a new tab with the same process. The command that I run in one tab runs in another tab as well. Is there a way to start a new tab with new terminator process?

Comment: Can you give an example of a process you have in one tab that shows up in a new tap?  Can you run this test and describe what you see?  Start the command `top` in a terminal.  Then open another terminal.  Do you see the top output in the second tab?  Also what happens if you click on Tabs in the menu and click detach.  Do you see two terminals running Top?  Now what happens if you quit top in one of the terminals, does it quit in the previous terminal also?  Do you have this same behavior if you create a new terminal with `Ctl + Alt + T`?

Comment: I added a tab to an existing window using Ctl + Shift + T. When I start top in one tab, I don't see top output in another.  This hold true after detaching the tab as well. Ctl + Alt + T also starts a new process. I closed the terminator window in which I observed the "same process behavior" and when I open a new window, it works as expected (I get new processes in each new tab I open). I'm not sure why terminator was opening same processes in the window I was working earlier. I might have typed some command unknowingly which led to this behavior. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What program is running in the terminal when you hit `ctl + Alt + T`?

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> are helpful shortcuts in terminator.
They open a new instance adjacent to the one you have, but without it being another window.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close it.

Comment: What about new tab (as browser tab)?

Comment: Press `ctrl` while clicking on the link you want to open. :)

Comment: @VitaliiDiravka `Ctrl-Shift-T` does the trick.